# Show different page templates for custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using the Custom Post Type UI plugin for worpdress and have created custom "pages". I have set these pages to be able to use the page template dropdown but would like to know if anyone knows of a way to show separate page templates for different post types?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the [`theme_page_templates`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/) filter hook to remove the templates that you do not want to see for each post type. When the templates are loaded, including for display in the edit screen the templates that are returned are first passed to this function:

```
apply_filters ( 'theme_page_templates', array $page_templates, WP_Theme $this, WP_Post|null $post )
```

To implement you will use something like the following code:

```
function filter_theme_page_templates( $templates, $theme, $post ){
    // make sure we have a post so we know what to filter
    if ( !empty( $post ) ){

        // get the post type for the current post
        $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

        // switch on the post type
        switch( $post_type ){
            case 'custom-post-type':
                // remove anything we don't want shown for the custom post type
                // array is keyed on the template filename
                unset( $templates['page-template-filename.php'] );
                break;
            default:
                // if there is no match it will return everything
                break;
        }
    }

    // return the (maybe) filtered array of templates
    return $templates;
}
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'filter_theme_page_templates', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi, would this involve excluding every template filename inside the array? What happens when we get to 50+ templates? would this not be laborious?

I was hoping of setting different subfolders for different cpt's

Comment: This is how it works in WordPress. It might be somewhat laborious, but from my experience there shouldn't be that many templates, and they shouldn't change that often. If you want to make it programmatic you can you the above code as the base for a plugin that lets you control it via the UI, but that's obviously out of scope for this question.

Comment: And if you want to exclude "everything" just return an empty array for the post types you don't want to show them for. Or if you just want 1 you could copy it from the `$templates` array into a new array and return that.

Comment: I use page templates for landing pages, hence the large amount of templates

Comment: Depends on your specific situation but there are some themes out there like Divi that let you set a specific layout per page, but that might not work for your users. It is possible to do what you want, and the code above is the starting point, but it will be some programming work. Good luck!